# Grouping dataframe rows based on variable in a separate, linked dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

Say I have two dataframes, one containing environmental data (`env.df`) and the other species occurrences (`species.df`), both with identical row names. I want to group the rows in `species.df` based on the values of a column (Year) in `env.df`, and then calculate statistics for each year individually.

```r
env.df:

              Site  Year
A2015           A    2015
A2016           A    2016
A2017           A    2017
B2015           B    2015
B2016           B    2016
B2017           B    2017

species.df:

               Species1  Species 2 Species 3
A2015             1          1          1
A2016             0          0          1
A2017             0          0          1
B2015             1          0          1
B2016             1          1          1
B2017             1          1          0
```

I don't want to add any more columns to `species.df` as the statistical functions I need to use can only deal with a presence-absence sample-by-species dataset. I know how to select samples from each year individually- `species.df[env.df$Year== '2015',]` and so on- but I could do with a single line of code that repeats this every year. I can only get the `dplyr` group_by function to work on `env.df` and don't know how to extend it to the linked species.df

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an advice, since I am not giving code that respect your constrains. But I have also dealt with ecological data, and packages like "vegan" that require column-based data.

My suggestion is to merge the two data.frames, and when you need to run the test, subset this data.frame accordingly (e.g. using `x[,3:7]`, or dplyr's `select()`). It will be easier and much more understandable for future readers (including yourself) than keeping them separated and running code full of for loops and merges.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
lapply(
  with(env.df, split(row.names(env.df), Year)),
  function(k) species.df[k, ]
)
```

gives

```
$`2015`
      Species1 Species2 Species3
A2015        1        1        1
B2015        1        0        1

$`2016`
      Species1 Species2 Species3
A2016        0        0        1
B2016        1        1        1

$`2017`
      Species1 Species2 Species3
A2017        0        0        1
B2017        1        1        0
```

---

Or

```
split(
  cbind(
    env.df,
    species.df[match(row.names(species.df), row.names(env.df)), ]
  ),
  env.df$Year
)
```

which gives

```
$`2015`
      Site Year Species1 Species2 Species3
A2015    A 2015        1        1        1
B2015    B 2015        1        0        1

$`2016`
      Site Year Species1 Species2 Species3
A2016    A 2016        0        0        1
B2016    B 2016        1        1        1

$`2017`
      Site Year Species1 Species2 Species3
A2017    A 2017        0        0        1
B2017    B 2017        1        1        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Or we use `merge` and `split` in `base R`

```
out <- merge(env.df, species.df, by = 'row.names')
row.names(out) <- out$Row.names
split(out[startsWith(names(out), 'Species')], out$Year)
```